# Joining two tables with aggregrate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables I need to combine. My first table(Foreign table) has the id's for literally all objects. Table A has people upvote id's  from Foreign Table and Table B has people downvote id's from Foreign Table.

I want to combine these 3 tables into 1 big table with counts in them. See the result table. Count table A refers to the amount of times the specific id is present in table A. How do I combine these to the final table?

**Foreign Table**

```
id
---
1           
2           
3   
...
```

**Table A**

```
id | foreign_id
-----------------------
1           3
2           3
3           1
```

**Table B**

```
id | foreign_id
-----------------------
1           3
2           1
3           2
```

**Result Table**

```
id | count table A   | count table B
------------------------------------
1           1           1
2           0           1
3           2           1
```

Comment: You will want to do this as @scaisEdge has answered. Notice that the answer is using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, this is because it will allow for instances where you do not have any entries in Tables A and B, otherwise you will not get a row even when there is an entry in one table and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the fastest method is a a correlated subquery:

```
select f.*,
       (select count(*) from a where a.foreign_id = f.id) as a_cnt,
       (select count(*) from b where b.foreign_id = f.id) as b_cnt
from foreign f;
```

This avoids the `GROUP BY` on the outer query.  As a bonus it can use an index on `a(foreign_id)` and `b(foreign_id)` which also benefit performance.

Comment: This one works without any problems, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

for manage properly the 0 result  you could use sum  and check for null

```
    select f.id
      , sum( when a.foreign_id is null then 0 else 1 end ) count_a
      , sum( when b.foreign_id is null then 0 else 1 end ) count_b
    from Foreign f 
    LEFT JOIN TableA a f.id = a.foreign_id
    LEFT JOIN TableA a f.id = b.foreign_id
    GROUP BY f.id
```

Comment: This mostly works and does what I want. Except for the fact that sometimes it is counting incorrectly. It gives me a number for count_b that is 1 higher than it should be.

If I just run a query using count(a.foreign_id) it does show the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

You can join, aggregate by the primary key of the foreign table and count distinct values of the primary keys of `table_a` and `table_b`:

```
select
    f.id,
    count(distinct a.id) count_table_a,
    count(distinct b.id) count_table_b
from foreign_table f
left join table_a a on a.foreign_id = f.id
left join table_b b on b.foreign_id = f.id
group by f.id
```

`count()` returns `0` where there is no match, so there is no need for special processing unlike when suming.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b539859d1de4621a3343af0a898e81b2)**:

```
id | count_table_a | count_table_b
-: | ------------: | ------------:
 1 |             1 |             1
 2 |             0 |             1
 3 |             2 |             1
```

Comment: This will only give you a 1 or a 0 in each row. It only takes one of each a.id/b.id instead of counting them all up.

Comment: @jdk94: you see the results of the tests in my answer, it is not made of 0s and 1s right? It also matches your expected results. Now if you want to allow repeated ids for a given foreign key (which is not showing in your sample data), you can remove `distinct` from the `count()`.

Comment: My bad, I did not give that information. If I remove the distinct it seems that, for id=3, count_table_a = 2 and count_table_b = 2. Which is incorrect as it is supposed to be 2 and 1. (I tried this in your DB Fiddle)

Comment: @jdk94: `count(distinct)` produces the expected results, as you can see. If that’s not what you want, you would need to come up with sample data that is representative of your use case...

Comment: Repeated foreign id's is showing in my data though, table A id 1 and 2. But someone else solved it

Answer (score 0):

I guess below would work

```
   Select f.id, count(a.*),count(b.*) from 
    foreign f
   Left Join
   tableA a on f.id=a.foreignid
   Join
   TableB b on f.id=b.foreignid

   Group by f.id
```

Or

```
  Select id, * from foreign f left join
  ( 
  Select foreignid, count(*) from tableA a
  group 
   by foreignid join
 Select foreignid, count(*) from tableB b
   group 
   by foreignid on 
  a.foreignid<b.foreignid) t on 
  f.id=t.foreignid;
```